# QJson for Linux - Unsure How to Use QJSON Correctly

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qjson

### Some Background

Originally made a project on mac, now I want to use my Linux machine for the same project. The settings folder relied on:

```
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonParseError>
```

These weren't included in my qt-devel install for SL5 - it uses QT v4. So I downloaded [QJson from Sourceforge](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/build/) and installed using cmake. Some example output:

```
--Installing: /usr/include/qjson/parser.h
--Installing /usr/lib/libqjson.so
```

That's fine. So I added to my .pro:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/ -lqjson
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qjson/
```

### The Actual Problem

Now I have the task of translating my old `settings.cpp` file to parse data in this slightly new method.

```
{
  "HwDescription": {
    "ConnectionsName": "file://settings/connections.xml",
    "ShelveId": 0,
    "BeBoard": {
      "Id": 10,
      "connectionId": "board0",
      "boardType": "GLIB"
    }, // + more boring stuff
```

So now I have this json above in a QString, just as I did for my old working method, then I try to parse as per the instructions given to me. I used: `#include <qjson/parser.h>` and I don't think I need any forward declarations here.

```
    QJson::Parser parser;
    bool ok;
    QVariantMap result = parser.parse (raw_json, &ok).toMap(); //where raw_json is a QString - this is where I get an error
    if (!ok)
    {
      qFatal("An error occured during parsing");
      exit (1);
    }
```

The error I get:

> error: no matching function to call to 'Qjson::Parser:parse(QString&, bool)

If I remove the include, the error says:

> QJson has not been declared

So it must be finding the libraries at least. Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: If you look at the [`QJson::Parser`](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/docs/classQJson_1_1Parser.html) reference, you will see that there is no overload of `parse` that takes a `QString&` as argument.

Comment: I was following the tutorial. Is there a better library than this one? It was so much easier on the mac

Comment: You just have to use e.g. [`QString::toLatin1`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1) or similar functions to get the [`QbyteArray`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html) needed.

Comment: I think I might end up using a different JSON library with QT. The JSON method given by Luke seems a bit too verbose

Comment: @fiz He is telling you to use  `parser.parse (raw_json.toLatin1(), &ok)`

Comment: Ahh that worked - cheers, put it as an answer @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 1):

Comments aren't parsed by default in QJson.

Here is a small adaptation I made on my QJson logic to handle comments.  Notice the simple Regex to remove comments.

```
QFile file( filename );

  //File can't be opened!
if ( !file.open( QFile::ReadOnly ) )
{ 
  qDebug("Couldn't load config file: %s", filename.toLatin1().data());
  return;
} 

  //Strip out comments
QStringList list = QString( file.readAll() ).split('\n');
for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
  list[i].replace( QRegExp("//[^\"]*$"), "" );

//Load the file, converting into an object file
QJsonParseError e;
QJsonObject json = 
  QJsonDocument::fromJson( list.join('\n').toLatin1(), &e ).object();

//Was there an error?
if ( e.error != QJsonParseError::NoError )
{ 
  qDebug( "Json parse error: %s", e.errorString().toLatin1().data() );
  return;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me? - I can't use QJsonParseError as this is included in QT v5 and I'm using v4 - the whole reason I installed QJson. Unless it's in that library somewhere?